# Django Custom Primary Key Tries to insert Null

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

There are some constraints to this problem. We currently use a production database, with live Virtual Machine Statistics. We are trying to create a django interface, that interfaces with the tables we want our administrators to be able to edit. Thus, migrations are out of the question, for unless I have come to understand migrations wrong it will affect the current database structure and or data.

I matched the database structure exactly in my models.py file. However I have run into a few issues. One of the issues I have run into is when I try to add a new item under the admin control panel it will give me an integrity error as it is attempting to insert a null value for the field I have set as the primary key in the models.py file.

We are currently using an oracle database.

My Models.py not all of it but a sample of it.

```
class License(models.Model):
   license_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, editable = False, db_column='license_id')
   license_authority_id = models.ForeignKey(License_authoritie,  on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column='license_authority_id')
   product = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

   class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'licenses'
      ordering = ['product']

   def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
      return self.product

class Vm_license(models.Model):
   vm_license_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, db_column='vm_license_id')
   vm_id = models.ForeignKey(Vm,  on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column='vm_id')
   license = models.ManyToManyField(License)

   class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'vm_licenses'
```

The error I get:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/portal/vm_license/add/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEV"."VM_LICENSES"."VM_LICENSE_ID")
```

On top of that I have run into another problem.

For these two tables, under the vm_licenses section in the admin panel which is a table that holds all VM's and their assigned licenses. I need the ability to select multiple licenses at a time for each vm_id under the add section of the admin panel but i'm not quite sure how to do this.

admin.py code

```
class vm_license_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #list_display = ('vm_id', 'license_id')
    list_display = ('vm_id',)
    search_fields = ('vm_id__vm_name',)
    ordering = ('vm_id',)
    filter_horizontal = ('license',)

admin.site.register(Vm_license, vm_license_admin)
```

I also made an oracle trigger to auto increment a primary key if there is none, but im still getting the same error.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER license_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON vm_licenses
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT vm_license_seq.nextval
    INTO :new.vm_license_id 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

to be more percise I am using a manytomany field and it displays correctly when I goto add a new item before clicking save and getting the null error, however if I goto an existing item it will say table or view doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment on your question, but I do not have the reputation yet...
but can I suggest you post your relevant admin.py code? Perhaps there is something within it relating to the Null PK error.

With regards to the second part, a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) sounds more suitable.

Comment: I'm using manytomany field, when i go to add a new item before clicking save and getting the null error it will display correctly but when i go to an existing item it says table or view doesn't exist when using many to many.

Comment: Your admin.py code looks clean, so I cannot help with your first problem, as it is over my head.
You second problem, I misread you already had a ManyToManyField. This should create a `<select>` on the admin page with the property `multiple="multiple"`. This turns a drop-down select box into a 'select list', and you then hold control (on windows) to select multiple items in the list.